# NonNull in android studio error Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

'android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
how can it be solved

Comment: can you provide the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to the Android platform's internal annotations, which aren't the ones you want to use for your own code. For your code, you should import the AndroidX versions of those annotations:

[androidx.annotation.NonNull](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/NonNull)

[androidx.annotation.Nullable](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Nullable)

etc. (note the extra x in androidx vs android)

You'll also want to make sure you have declared a dependency on androidx.annotation:annotation in your build.gradle (see here for the latest version information)

import that annotation class:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

which is either coming from this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0"
```

or from this dependency, in case not yet using android:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
```

then you can use it as usual:

```
 @NonNull
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'

Comment: I am edited my answer please go through it. Happy Coding :)